# Please make the old "mexican-fm-t" tag a synonym of the new "fmm" tag

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

The Mexican FMT was replaced by the new FMM back in 2010, the same year our site went into beta.

Since the old tag was only used twice and the tag wiki wasn't too detailed I just went ahead and made a new [fmm](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fmm) tag.

I didn't add the `mexican-` prefix since we don't have an `american-` prefix on the tag [esta](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esta) or an `australian-` prefix on the tag [eta](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eta), and though other countries have a thing called a "tourist card" nobody else has an "FMM" so far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1):

FMM is the airport code for Memmingen Allgau airport, so I'd go for [mexican-fmm](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mexican-fmm) on this occasion (although I understand the rationale for not initially suggesting so). If people agree, I'm happy to make this synonym.

Comment: We've had tags that collide with airport codes for years. I even wrote at app for it years ago. We'll have to change ones like [tag:eta], [tag:bus], [tag:usa], [tag:tsa], etc if that's the policy. In fact we discussed it as a policy years ago too.

Comment: [tag:fmm] is main now, with [tag:mexican-fm-t] as synonym :)

Comment: I do agree in general that airport codes take precedence once they are used on the site. At which time any three-letter tags no matter how widely used would then be renamed.

Comment: I'd go for the mexican- prefix. IMHO the more verbose the tag, the better.